# Can't affect divs with javascript when using node.js?

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, pug, stylus

I'm probably doing something obviously wrong but I'm using node.js and I have a javascript file linked properly (`alert("hello");` works). But I can't affect anything with the DOM. Simple example:

jade:

```
doctype html
html
    head
        link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/styles.css')
        script(src='/javascripts/script.js')
    body
        block index_block
        div#divClassName
```

stylus:

```
#divClassName
    background-color red
    width 200px
    height 200px
```

js:

```
alert("hello");

var div = document.getElementById("divClassName");

div.style.backgroundColor = "green";
```

The box remains red. Why? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your script is ran before the HTML has been read, the `div` variables returns undefined since no such element exists at the time your script is executed. Wrapping your JS in a function `onload` of the document allows you to defer execution until the document has been fully loaded.

```
window.onload = function(){
    alert("hello"); 
    var div = document.getElementById("divClassName");
    div.style.backgroundColor = "green";
}
```